# Cannot load a bitmap using the winapi c++

Tags: c++, winapi

I am pretty new to c++ and the windows api and am currently trying to create a calculator application. I would like to place images of certain mathematical symbols on buttons, but I am having trouble getting the images to load. Whenever I use LoadImage() or LoadBitmap() to try and load the image, the function returns null.

In a resource file, I have written:

```
SQROOT                 BITMAP                "sqroot.bmp"
```

In a file called Resource.h, I have written:

```
#define SQROOT 201
```

In order to load the bmp, I have tried:

```
HBITMAP bmp = (HBITMAP)LoadImage((HINSTANCE)GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE), MAKEINTRESOURCE(SQROOT), IMAGE_BITMAP, 20, 20, LR_DEFAULTCOLOR);
if (bmp == NULL) {
    MessageBox(hWnd, L"Image failed to load", L"Error", 1);
}
```

I have also tried:

```
HBITMAP bmp = LoadBitmap((HINSTANCE)GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE), MAKEINTRESOURCE(SQROOT));
if (bmp == NULL) {
        MessageBox(hWnd, L"Image failed to load", L"Error", 1);
    }
```

In the resource file, I have also tried putting the complete path to the bmp but that also did not work.
Both of these functions return null, would anyone happen to know what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: `GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE)` looks odd to me.  I certainly never do that.  Try `GetModuleHandle(nullptr)` instead, or use the `hInstance` passed to `WinMain`.

Comment: Here's how I do it: `HBITMAP bmp = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(SQROOT), IMAGE_BITMAP,20,20, NULL);`

Comment: Did you verify with a resource editor/viewer that the bitmaps are actually in the compiled EXE file?

Comment: `GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE)` should work just fine, provided that this code is in a `WndProc` being registered via `RegisterClass/Ex()`, and the correct `HINSTANCE` is being specified in the `WNDCLASS/EX::hInstance` field.

Comment: What did GetLastError(0 say?  ("If the function fails, the return value is NULL. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.")

Comment: I believe that I may have identified the problem. When I opened the exe file using visual studio and when I tried to open the bitmap, it threw the error, "Unknown bitmap format.". Does anyone know why this is the case or how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: @DaveS `GetLastError` usually returns `ERROR_SUCCESS` when image loading fails. Not very helpful. The pragmatic solution to this problem: Always load an image into MS Paint, and save it. MS Paint has seen so many invalid image files that it knows how to right the wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When opening the executable using visual studio, I discovered that my bitmap was in an invalid format. To solve this issue, I imported the bitmap into Microsoft Paint and then exported it back into my project and that solved the issue.